# Gradle Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm new to Gradle and I'm trying to configure it to build rosjava. I believe that I have a relatively simple multi-project configuration. Everything builds, tests, and installs to my local Maven repo via gradle install. However, when I attempt to use the Eclipse plugin to generate .project and .classpath files, it fails:

```
Execution failed for task ':rosjava:eclipseClasspath'.
  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
  > Module version group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT, configuration:detachedConfiguration1 declares a dependency on configuration 'archives' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava_bootstrap, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I'm not exactly sure how to debug this. The basic layout of the project is:

```
rosjava_core/build.gradle
rosjava_core/rosjava/build.gradle
rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/build.gradle
```

The rosjava project depends upon rosjava_bootstrap like so:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':rosjava_bootstrap')
}
```

The rosjava_bootstrap project has no dependencies.

Here are the gory details:

```
~/ros/workspace/rosjava_core$ gradle rosjava:eclipse -i --stacktrace
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using settings file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'rosjava_core', project ':apache_xmlrpc_client', project ':apache_xmlrpc_common', project ':apache_xmlrpc_server', project ':rosjava', project ':rosjava_actionlib', project ':rosjava_actionlib_tutorial', project ':rosjava_bootstrap', project ':rosjava_geometry', project ':rosjava_tut
orial_pubsub']
Evaluating root project 'rosjava_core' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':apache_xmlrpc_client' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_client/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':apache_xmlrpc_common' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_common/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':apache_xmlrpc_server' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/apache_xmlrpc_server/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava_actionlib' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_actionlib/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava_actionlib_tutorial' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_actionlib_tutorial/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava_bootstrap' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava_geometry' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_geometry/build.gradle'.
Evaluating project ':rosjava_tutorial_pubsub' using build file '/home/damonkohler/ros/workspace/rosjava_core/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/build.gradle'.
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'rosjava:eclipse'
Tasks to be executed: [task ':rosjava:eclipseClasspath', task ':rosjava:eclipseJdt', task ':rosjava:eclipseProject', task ':rosjava:eclipse']
:rosjava:eclipseClasspath
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/damonkohler/gradle-1.0-milestone-8a/lib/ivy-2.2.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rosjava:eclipseClasspath'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Module version group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT, configuration:detachedConfiguration1 declares a dependency on configuration 'archives' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava_bootstrap, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':rosjava:eclipseClasspath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:250)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:238)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:222)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
C    aused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.access$000(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$BrokenResolvedConfiguration.getLenientConfiguration(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:123)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.getFiles(IdeDependenciesExtractor.groovy:219)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.this$2$getFiles(IdeDependenciesExtractor.groovy)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor$this$2$getFiles.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.extractRepoFileDependencies(IdeDependenciesExtractor.groovy:99)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor$extractRepoFileDependencies.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathFactory$4.update(ClasspathFactory.groovy:56)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathEntryBuilder$update.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathFactory.createEntries(ClasspathFactory.groovy:82)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathFactory$createEntries.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.resolveDependencies(EclipseClasspath.groovy:213)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.mergeXmlClasspath(EclipseClasspath.groovy:220)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath$mergeXmlClasspath.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.GenerateEclipseClasspath.configure(GenerateEclipseClasspath.groovy:45)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.GenerateEclipseClasspath.configure(GenerateEclipseClasspath.groovy)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.api.XmlGeneratorTask$1.configure(XmlGeneratorTask.java:41)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.api.XmlGeneratorTask$1.configure(XmlGeneratorTask.java:35)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.api.GeneratorTask.generate(GeneratorTask.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.GenerateEclipseClasspath_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:495)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:484)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Module version group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT, configuration:detachedConfiguration1 declares a dependency on configuration 'archives' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava_bootstrap, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:322)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:283)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:117)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:237)
        ... 81 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.347 secs
```

And the version of gradle:

```
~/ros/workspace/rosjava_core$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.0-milestone-8a
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, February 20, 2012 4:00:18 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.4
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_20 (Sun Microsystems Inc. 19.0-b09)
OS: Linux 2.6.32-37-generic amd64
```

The full source and build scripts are available here: http://code.google.com/r/damonkohler-rosjava-unstable/source/browse

Comment: Could you post the full output from running gradle? What version are you using? Which directory are you running it in?

Comment: I updated the question with additional details.

Comment: Might it be as simple as "running gradle" eclipse rather than "gradle rosjava:eclipse"? It seems like it can't find that other module, perhaps because it's not part of the sub-directory build

Comment: Sorry, quotes in the wrong place. Should read: running "gradle eclipse"

Comment: No. That fails in the same manner after generating some eclipse files for other sub projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing my dependencies as described [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/maven_plugin_install_task_not_being_called), this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The java plugin defines the "archives" configuration, so one possibility is that you apply the java plugin to each submodules. It is also possible to define your own archives configuration without the plugin. Here is what I use in my non-java submodule:

```
task jar(type: Jar, dependsOn: compile) {
    from file("build")
    destinationDir=file("dist")
    archiveName="my-custom-archive.jar"
}

configurations {
    archives
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using the java plugin. The source and build scripts are visible here: http://code.google.com/r/damonkohler-rosjava-unstable/source/browse

Patches welcome ;)

Comment: I tried running it on my (Windows) machine but the same version of Gradle, and it finished without error http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=fx7HdRQA. I'm sorry that I could not be more help.

Comment: Thanks. I found that it actually works for me as well if I haven't run gradle install first. And, it turns out that if I clear my .m2 cache, gradle install fails. I posted a question on the gradle forums about that: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/maven_plugin_install_task_not_being_called